# How can I coordinate various DLLs in the same process, without help from the host program?

Tags: c, windows, dll

I am looking for a way to coordinate DLLs in the same process, in order to provide a data sharing mechanism between them. The goal is to have the same sharing code for all DLLs, and to have them coordinate in such a way that the first one loaded by the main program will act as the manager for shared items, while the others will use this manager. I cannot modify the main application, so having that set up the manager and sharing its memory address with the other DLLs is not possible. The set of DLLs using this mechanism can vary, so I cannot assume explicitly that one of them will be loaded.

One solution I considered is to add the memory address to the environment variables of the process. The first DLL would see that the environment variable is not set yet, create the manager object and set the variable to its address. The other DLLs would see the variable and create a pointer to the manager object from that.

This comes close to what I want, but it seems a bit crude, since there is no guarantee that the environment variable isn't set already for some reason, and SetEnvironmentVariable/GetEnvironmentVariable can fail for various reasons.

Is there a better way to handle this? I'm looking for a way to store and retreive a named pointer in the context of a process, but if you have a better solution for the underlying problem of getting the DLLs to cooperate I'd be happy to accept this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine [`GetModuleHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [`GetProcAddress()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to achieve this.  The dependent DLLs will obtain the handle to the manager DLL, and then use `GetProcAddress()` to retrieve pointers from the symbols that it exports.

Or just dynamically link the dependent DLLs against the manager DLLs and use a header file for the extern definitions.

---

I misread your question initially; however, the above approach can still be useful.

You can require that these DLLs all export an identical symbol that will point to some structure or function.  Then, when one of the libraries is initialized, it can enumerate the loaded modules in the process and look for that symbol.  If dereferencing the pointer returned by `GetProcAddress()` returns a null pointer, then this module is the first one loaded and should create the required structure and set its own variable.  Otherwise, it uses the value obtained from the pointer.

This method is fraught with race-conditions though, if these modules can be initialized concurrently.  You would be better off having a single supervisor module that each module can use as a communication point.

Comment: I considered this, but I'd prefer not to have one dedicated manager DLL. The DLLs are Game Maker extensions, and to follow the route you suggest, the manager DLL would either need to be included in every extension which uses this system, or included manually by the programmer who wants to use the extensions, and I'd like to avoid this extra dependency.

Comment: @cdhowie, modules cannot be initialized simultaneously on Windows; the loader lock ensures only one DLL's entry point can be executed at a time

Comment: @Medo42: And the solution is to have each DLL provide its own manager?  What happens when you need to upgrade the manager?  If any one module implements an older version and it gets loaded first, the process will be forced to use an older version.  Dependencies can be annoying, but this situation will quickly become a *worse* version of DLL hell, since which version of the manager gets loaded can be unpredictable.  Don't subject your developers to that.  A strong dependency with proper header files will make your life (and those of your developers) so much easier in the long run.

Comment: @bdonlan: Nothing says that initialization has to happen in the DLL entry point.  It could happen in an exported function that gets called by the code responsible for loading the library.

Comment: @cdhowie, it could, but if you at least negotiate the master DLL in the entry point you can avoid simultaneity.

Comment: @cdhowie, your edited solution looks very good, and your comment is doing a good job of convincing me that this is not such a good idea after all. :)

Answer (score 2):

how about creating a [named shared memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ?

that would allow you to share a part of memory, without the hassle of obtaining an address valid in the process context. the first DLL loaded creates the shared memory, the next DLL can then directly access the memory, you can build your own messaging API on top of this.

Comment: And make sure you wrap access with mutexes and the like, because you will have concurrent access. +Thanks @Adrien Plisson, you link helped me solve a somewhat related problem I had.

Comment: This would generally work, but extra care would be required since named shared memory is shared between processes, which I explicitly do not want. Still upvote for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

cdhowie provides some good reasons why this is a bad idea.

However, if you really want to do this, without polluting the global shared memory namespace: Register a window class in your DLL entry point, but pass the EXE's instance as the `hInstance` field of the window class.

Each DLL can check if the class is already registered; if not, register itself. The first DLL to successfully register the window class becomes the master. To obtain a pointer to some structure initialized by the master in the subsequently loaded DLLs, then, create a message-only window of that class, and use `SendMessage` to invoke its window procedure (in the master DLL).